# How to Stucture Multi-Product Work with Maven?

Tags: maven, build, structure

Let's assume I am developing multiple software products. In this case, a Product is something I want to build and is (usually) not a dependency of another Product. Products depend on libraries.

Take the following dependencies as an example, I believe this is a polytree:

```
ProductA
├── lib_a
└── lib_b

ProductB
├── lib_b
└── lib_c
```

[image: Dependency graph]

*(In real life the number of products and libraries is much greater)*

As I work on each product, I usually make changes on both the Product and it's dependencies. I want to structure my work so that when I build the project, I also build all of it's dependencies.

As I make changes, I also update the versions of each Product and library and store these to version control. However, I do not want to update the versions of products and libraries that are not changed.

Assume that i want to use Maven to build my projects. How should I structure them so that I can always build the entire Product? Can I use multiple version control repositories?

Answer (score 1):

A simple proposal for your requirements could look like this:

```
Parent POM                                   <-- <packaging>pom</packaging>
   module ProductA  (dependencies: a and b)  <-- <packaging>jar</packaging>
   module ProductB  (dependencies: b and c)
   module lib_a                              <-- <packaging>jar</packaging>
   module lib_b
   module lib_c
```

This would build, install and deploy all your artifacts with a single command. This would require a corresponding folder structure - the modules should better be on the same level. In theory it is possible to put them into different repositories, but this would break Maven Release plugin.

Comment: "would break Maven Release plugin" - how exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said **could** - I'm just talking from experience - Maven Release plugin makes really a lot and is very sensitive to changing defaults. After googling, I found out that it really breaks: [Maven release plugin, multiple svn repos?](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-release-plugin-multiple-svn-repos-td5717816.html)

Comment: This has been asked frequently, so I have just created a screencast of how to manage multi-module projects with Idea in a brisk manner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20163892/1851024. Might be helpful...