# Install Maven for two or more projects with one pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, pom.xml

I'm new to maven..

I have three different projects in the same workspace and I want to install Maven in the three projects with only one pom.xml in order to avoid doing it one at a time and manually, just run the maven install in Project 1 and automatically have installed maven in the other two projects.

I don't know if there's a maven plugin that do this task?

Anyone has good solution for this, a really need help with this!

Regards

Comment: To clarify, you don't want to *install* Maven for multiple projects. Maven is installed, and you want to configure multiple projects to be related to each other, probably as project modules.

Answer (score 0):

create a multi-module project: [maven aggregation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation)

Comment: Thank's for the tip, it help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a multi-module project. Here is the quickest way for me to do it with Idea: [How to create an empty multi module Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20163892/1851024)

Comment: Thank's for the tip, it help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maven is designed for a pom.xml for each project.  You can save time by having a multi module Pom pointing to all three modules so you can use maven install there.  The easiest for a workspace with multiple projects is to have it at the root of the workspace.

Comment: Thank's for the tip, it help me a lot!