# Dependency error in eclipse project making use of Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am using Eclipse Mars to run my Java project. I am making use of Maven in it. But while trying to compile my package I am getting the following error.

> Failed to execute goal on project apex-check: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.fundacionjala.enforce.sonarqube:apex-check:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.fundacionjala.enforce.sonarqube:apex-squid:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.fundacionjala.enforce.sonarqube:apex-squid:jar:1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.fundacionjala.enforce.sonarqube:apex-squid:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy -> [Help 1].

I am able to find that my pom.xml has a bug in its dependency. But don't know how to resolve it. I have given below my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!-- ~ Copyright (c) Fundacion Jala. All rights reserved. ~ Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information. -->

 <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


 <parent>

 <groupId>org.fundacionjala.enforce.sonarqube</groupId>

 <artifactId>apex</artifactId>

 <version>1.0b${build.number}</version>

 </parent>

 <artifactId>apex-check</artifactId>

 <name>Apex :: Checks</name>


 <dependencies>


 <dependency>

 <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>

 <artifactId>apex-squid</artifactId>

 <version>${project.version}</version>

 </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

I have written 'apex-check' and 'apex-squid' as two separate projects.
[image]
Can anyone explain how to correct my pom.xml?

Comment: How should we know the correct proxy settings for *your* network?

Comment: I have given my proxy settings correctly. In my maven, settings file and Eclipse network settings, I have given all the necessary informations.

Comment: Tell maven that. Have you checked your maven settings in the eclipse plug-in? Does it work from the command line outside of eclipse?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is right. Your proxy settings are either wrong or at the wrong place.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have:

```
org.fundacionjala.enforce.sonarqube:apex-check:jar:1.0
org.fundacionjala.enforce.sonarqube:apex-squid:jar:1.0
```

jar files available in your local .m2/repository folder. If they are not present maven will try to download from central repository and as an expected result it will fail on firewall or it will not find the artifact. i.e. if:
`apex-check` requires `apex-squid` project as dependency first you need to install squid project files by using `mvn install` on squid project folder.

But it seems more like you want to create a multi module maven project, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328778/how-to-create-an-empty-multi-module-maven-project). Create a parent project similar to this project, add `check` and `squid` as module and run `mvn clean install` on parent.

**edit: I just see you already have parent, so make sure parent has your projects as modules, which helps reactive build order and eclipse imports

Comment: I even added my 'apex-squid:jar:1.0' to my project 'apex-check'. Still no improvement.