# Unable to create maven parent project from command line

Tags: maven

I am trying to generate empty maven parent project from command line using below command:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DgroupId=demo-group \
-DartifactId=multi-module-demo \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart \
-DinteractiveMode=false \
-Dpackaging=pom
```

Project is getting generated but its generating 'jar' packaging instead of 'pom'. Even though I mentioned -Dpackaging=pom in the command. Please suggest if I am missing anything in this command.

I am using maven 3.6.0

Answer (score 2):

If you choose [maven-archetype-quickstart](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/) as the archetype it creates a project with a java file which should then be packaged in a jar. So setting packaging=pom makes no sense here, hence you just can not do it.

Found an old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328778/how-to-create-an-empty-multi-module-maven-project)

So in your case you can create it with:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=pom-root \
-DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE \
-DgroupId=demo-group \
-DartifactId=multi-module-demo \
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can create project with pom package.